# How to install a Beta (Crashlytics) distributed application on Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

In some android tv box is possible to use beta by crashlytics with a poor user interface (portrait mode makes screen rotated, no focus on buttons, etc), but in some devices there is no navigation possible, as there is no way to access to install button.
Is there another way to install an apk in an Android TV device?

Comment: Have you checked this post by UDACITY focusing on ["Simplifying Android app distribution with Beta by Crashlytics"](https://engineering.udacity.com/simplifying-app-distribution-with-beta-by-crashlytics-6c8c24f4ab02)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is that the Android Beta app it is not prepared for Android TV devices, and in some cases doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is not officially supported. While there are a few devices that you might be able to make this work on, most won't work at all.